# How Convexity Defect is calculated in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, convex-hull, convexity-defects

What is the algorithm used in OpenCV function [`convexityDefects()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gada4437098113fd8683c932e0567f47ba) to calculate the convexity defects of a contour?

Please, describe and illustrate the high-level operation of the algorithm, along with its inputs and outputs.

Comment: The inputs are described in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gada4437098113fd8683c932e0567f47ba) -- two lists of coordinates, one defining the contour, the other defining the convex hull corresponding to that contour. The library is open source, so you can [read the implementation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/808ba552c532408bddd5fe51784cf4209296448a/modules/imgproc/src/convhull.cpp#L268) -- if there's some specific part of the algorithm you don't understand, feel free to ask a concrete question.

Comment: Im looking for the explanation for the implementation, i mean in words, not by program.

Comment: OK, hope that explains it. Nevertheless, it's valuable to read the code too, and try to understand it -- it's an excellent way to learn, an essential skill for a programmer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gada4437098113fd8683c932e0567f47ba), the input are two lists of coordinates:

- `contour` defining the original contour (red on the image below)
- `convexhull` defining the convex hull corresponding to that contour (blue on the image below)

[image: Example contour and convex hull]

The [algorithm](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/808ba552c532408bddd5fe51784cf4209296448a/modules/imgproc/src/convhull.cpp#L268) works in the following manner:

If the contour or the hull contain 3 or less points, then the contour is always convex, and no more processing is needed. The algorithm assures that both the contour and the hull are accessed in the same orientation.

***N.B.:*** In further explanation I assume they are in the same orientation, and ignore the details regarding representation of the floating point depth as an integer.

Then for each pair of adjacent hull points (`H[i]`, `H[i+1]`), defining one edge of the convex hull, calculate the distance from the edge for each point on the contour `C[n]` that lies between `H[i]` and `H[i+1]` (excluding `C[n] == H[i+1]`). If the distance is greater than zero, then a defect is present. When a defect is present, record `i`, `i+1`, the maximum distance and the index (`n`) of the contour point where the maximum located.

Distance is calculated in the following manner:

```
dx0 = H[i+1].x - H[i].x
dy0 = H[i+1].y - H[i].y

if (dx0 is 0) and (dy0 is 0) then
    scale = 0
else
    scale = 1 / sqrt(dx0 * dx0 + dy0 * dy0)

dx = C[n].x - H[i].x
dy = C[n].y - H[i].y

distance = abs(-dy0 * dx + dx0 * dy) * scale
```

It may be easier to visualize in terms of vectors:

- **`C`**: defect vector from `H[i]` to `C[n]`
- **`H`**: hull edge vector from `H[i]` to `H[i+1]`
- **`H_rot`**: hull edge vector **`H`** rotated 90 degrees
- **`U_rot`**: unit vector in direction of **`H_rot`**

**`H`** components are `[dx0, dy0]`, so rotating 90 degrees gives `[-dy0, dx0]`.

`scale` is used to find **`U_rot`** from **`H_rot`**, but because divisions are more computationally expensive than multiplications, the inverse is used as an optimization. It's also pre-calculated before the loop over `C[n]` to avoid recomputing each iteration.

|**`H`**| = sqrt(dx0 * dx0 + dy0 * dy0)

**`U_rot`**  = **`H_rot`** / |**`H`**| = **`H_rot`** * `scale`

Then, a dot product between **`C`** and **`U_rot`** gives the perpendicular distance from the defect point to the hull edge, and `abs()` is used to get a positive magnitude in any orientation.

distance = abs(**`U_rot`**.**`C`**) = abs(-dy0 * dx + dx0 * dy) * scale

---

In the scenario depicted on the above image, in first iteration, the edge is defined by `H[0]` and `H[1]`. The contour points tho examine for this edge are `C[0]`, `C[1]`,  and `C[2]` (since `C[3] == H[1]`).

[image: First edge]

There are defects at `C[1]` and `C[2]`. The defect at `C[1]` is the deepest, so the algorithm will record `(0, 1, 1, 50)`.

The next edge is defined by `H[1]` and `H[2]`, and corresponding contour point `C[3]`. No defect is present, so nothing is recorded.

The next edge is defined by `H[2]` and `H[3]`, and corresponding contour point `C[4]`. No defect is present, so nothing is recorded.

Since `C[5] == H[3]`, the last contour point can be ignored -- there can't be a defect there.

Comment: Nice illustrations! As additional verbal explanation for visualizing the `distance = abs(-dy0 * dx + dx0 * dy) * scale` calculation: it’s a dot product formed by projecting vectors from `H[i]` to each `C[n]` onto a unit vector in the hull segment direction from `H[i]` to `H[i+1]` that’s been rotated 90° (thus the `scale` and `dx0` <-> `dy0` swaps with the sign change.)

Comment: @rob3c Thanks. If you want, you can [edit] the answer, and add that explanation there.