# Python's cv2 convex defects distances are too large?

Tags: python, opencv, convex-hull, convexity-defects

UPDATE: it seems like the ratio between the distances I calculate myself and the distances returned by `cv2` is exactly 256. This is not surprising, since looking at their code (line 394 [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/45d073f8898c42a95ae54e2e83a827fc26ec336b/modules/imgproc/src/convhull.cpp)) shows the distances in pixels get multiplied by 256. I just don't understand why, I guess.

---

I am using `cv2.convexityDefects` to find, well, the convex defects of some shape. I wish to compute the depths (distances to the convex hull, [as nicely explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481157/how-convexity-defect-is-calculated-in-opencv)) of the defects.

However, the distances I get are way too large to make sense. I additionally tried to compute the distances manually, using the start and end point output arguments of cv2.convexityDefects (see code below), and get a more reasonable result.

The distances calculated by `cv2.convexityDefects` are,

```
>> d
array([21315, 26578, 19093, 56472, 35230, 20476, 26825], dtype=int32)
```

which make no sense at all in the context of the image, which ~500 pixels wide. What am I doing wrong?

---

**More info:**

This is an image (ehhr I mean work of art) I created for this test,

[image: test image for convex defects]

Here is a the code:

```
from numpy.linalg import norm

# Load an image
img = cv2.imread('buff.png')

# Threshold
ret, img = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Detect edges
edges = cv2.Canny(img, 1, 2)

# Find contours
cnts, h = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Find convex hull
hull = cv2.convexHull(cnts[0], returnPoints = False)

# Find defects
defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnts[0], np.sort(np.squeeze(hull)))
# Reshape the output
s = np.reshape(defects,(-1,4))[:,0] # start point idx
e = np.reshape(defects,(-1,4))[:,1] # end point idx
f = np.reshape(defects,(-1,4))[:,2] # defect idx
d = np.reshape(defects,(-1,4))[:,3] # distances as calculated by cv2.convexityDefects

# Draw contours in red, convex hull in blue
img = cv2.drawContours(img, cnts[0], -1, (255,0,0), 2)
img = cv2.polylines(img, [cnts[0][np.squeeze(hull)]], True, (0,0,255), 3)

# Calculate distances manually and put in a list d2
d2 = list()
for i in range(len(f)):
    # Draw the defects in blue, start points in pink:
    img = cv2.circle(img, tuple(cnts[0][f[i]][0]), 5,(0, 0, 255), -1)
    img = cv2.circle(img, tuple(cnts[0][s[i]][0]), 5,(255, 0, 255), -1)

    # Manually calculate the distances as the distances between the defects (blue points)
    # and the line defined between each pair of start and end points (pink here, for demonstration)
    d2.append(norm(np.cross(cnts[0][s[i]][0]-cnts[0][e[i]][0], cnts[0][e[i]][0]-cnts[0][f[i]][0]))/norm(cnts[0][s[i]][0]-cnts[0][e[i]][0]))
    
pp.imshow(img)
pp.show()
```

Here is the output of the above code, when applied on the test image:

[image: Convex pts as calculated by the code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the ratio between the distances I calculate myself and the distances returned by `cv2` is exactly 256. This is not surprising, since looking at their code (line 394 [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/45d073f8898c42a95ae54e2e83a827fc26ec336b/modules/imgproc/src/convhull.cpp)) shows the distances in pixels get multiplied by 256. I just don't understand why, I guess.